# Firebase: startAt() is not filtering data stored with keys as hours since epoch

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

My data is stored with keys as hours since epoch. I want to get only slice of the data - so for example I want to specify that I want all data starting at `453615`.

**So far I got this code:**

```
  this.dbService.databaseRef.child('dev_trends/' + this.deviceUid)
  .orderByKey()
  .startAt('453615')
  .get().then(dataTrends => {
    const data = dataTrends.val();

    console.log(data);
  });
```

**With the code above I get this results in my console:**

[image]

**My data model looks like this:**

[image]

### What should I change in my code so that I get the data from Firebase filtered?

---

**I create the databaseRef variable inside a service with this code:**

```
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    //Set what happens when we read all devices
    this.databaseRef = db.database.ref(); //Create databaseReference
  }
```

**Json of my data:**

```
  {"dev_trends" : {
    "-MkMxxZXXzmKclgeGPde" : {
      "H" : {
        "453614" : "50;45",
        "453615" : "50;50",
        "453617" : "50;55",
        "453630" : "51;60"
      },
      "T" : {
        "453614" : "24;18",
        "453615" : "23;17",
        "453617" : "23;15",
        "453630" : "22;10"
      }
    }
  }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find out where the problem was:**

- The `startAt()` method was filtering data with keys `H` and `T` and
  not the lists of data inside those keys.
- Solution was to restructure the data model.

**New data model:**

[image]

---

**Additional info:**

- I am not saying my solution is ideal - but for my specific problem it
  will do the trick.
- It will still require some additional work for me - so if anyone else has a better solution for this please post Your answer too :)